# Django widget tweaks 'render_field' not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, jinja2, django-widget-tweaks

I have this form rendering template in django, and `render_field` is not working inside `if-else`:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %} 
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }} 
        {% if form.is_bound %} 
            {% if field.errors %} 
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %} 
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {{error}}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %} 
            {% else %} 
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %} 
            {% endif %} 
        {% else %} 
            {% render_field field class="form-control" %} 
        {% endif %} 

        {% if field.help_text %}
            <small class="form-text text-muted">
               {{ field.help_text }}
            </small>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And it renders this:

[image]

But when I try a smaller version of the above code like following, then also it still doesn't work:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %} 
{% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">

            {% if field.errors %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
            {% else %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if field.help_text %}
                <small class="form-text text-muted">
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                </small>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And renders this:

[image]

But when I remove all `if-else`'s:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %} 
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }} 
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %} 
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <small class="form-text text-muted">
               {{ field.help_text }}
            </small>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then it renders correctly:

[image]

But I need the `if-else`'s to check for form errors and add error messages to form accordingly, will appreciate any help. **So why is `render_field` not working with `if-else` ? How to resolve this ? Any other ways to use `widget_tweaks` to render error or any alternative of `widget_tweaks` ?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`WIDGET_ERROR_CLASS`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) to set error class.

```
{% with WIDGET_ERROR_CLASS='my_error_class' %}
    {% render_field form.field1 %}
    {% render_field form.field2 %}
    {% render_field form.field3 %}
{% endwith %}
```

And then you can add form errors:

```
{% if field.errors %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{error}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```